# Vaadin Dataprovider: how to avoid "auto-fetch"?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Use Case 1 is answered below, Use Case 2 has been moved to a separate question ([Vaadin Flow: Returning to a view, the view should not reload data from the backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330474/vaadin-flow-returning-to-a-view-the-view-should-not-reload-data-from-the-backe))

I'd like to use a Vaadin Flow (v14 LTS/v19) grid component backed by a lazy `DataProvider` which does not automatically fetch data from the backend when the grid is shown.

There are at least two use cases:

- showing grid data does not make sense unless the user provided filter parameters
- returning to a `@PreserveOnRefresh` tagged view should not replace the shown data with current data. (further elaborated in update)

Being pretty new to Vaadin 14+, I could not figure out how to achieve this. Every time my `GridView` is displayed, the count and fetch callbacks of `DataProvider` are queried. The call originates from the `DataCommunicator` of the grid.

So for Use Case 1: How to stop the `DataProvider` from fetching data as long as it does not make sense?
And for Use Case 2: How to prevent overwriting the grid state when adding a grid to the UI for the second time?

Thanks a lot!

StackTrace to my fetch callback (Vaadin Flow 14):

```
        at org.vaadin.example.GridView.fetch(GridView.java:46)
        at org.vaadin.example.GridView.lambda$new$c4b2c115$1(GridView.java:23)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.CallbackDataProvider.fetchFromBackEnd(CallbackDataProvider.java:137)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.AbstractBackEndDataProvider.fetch(AbstractBackEndDataProvider.java:61)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.fetchFromProvider(DataCommunicator.java:362)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.activate(DataCommunicator.java:647)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.collectKeysToFlush(DataCommunicator.java:589)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.flush(DataCommunicator.java:461)
        at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.lambda$requestFlush$2f364bb9$1(DataCommunicator.java:425)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.lambda$runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse$2(StateTree.java:390)
        at [java.util.stream] omitted
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse(StateTree.java:387)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.encodeChanges(UidlWriter.java:411)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.createUidl(UidlWriter.java:187)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.writeUidl(UidlRequestHandler.java:122)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1547)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

---

update 20210430
Here's the code of my `GridView` which also fakes the backend `DataProvider`:

```
@Route(value = "grid", layout = MainView.class)
public class GridView extends VerticalLayout {
    public GridView() {
        final Grid<Person> g = new Grid(Person.class);
        g.setColumns("name");
        g.setDataProvider(DataProvider.fromCallbacks(q -> fetch(q), q -> count(q)));
        add(g);
        // filter omitted
        final Button refresh = new Button("refresh");
        refresh.addClickListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("refresh clicked");
            g.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
        });
        add(refresh);

        add(new TextField("State check"));
    }

    // fake DataProvider
    private int count(Query<Person, Void> q) { return 3; }

    private Stream<Person> fetch(Query<Person, Void> q) {
        q.getLimit(); //vaadin checks these have been called
        q.getOffset(); //vaadin checks these have been called
        System.out.println("fetching again");
        new Exception().printStackTrace(); //figure out who called
        return Arrays.asList(new Person("1"), new Person("2"), new Person("3")).stream();
    }
}
```

My `MainView` is used to switch between `GridView` and `EmptyView`

```
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MainView extends AppLayout {

    private Component emptyBView;
    private Component gridBView;

    public MainView() {
        final Button emptyB = new Button("Btn empty");
        emptyB.addClickListener(e -> {
            if (emptyBView == null) { emptyBView = new EmptyView();}
            setContent(emptyBView);
        });
        addToNavbar(emptyB);

        final Button gridB = new Button("Btn grid");
        gridB.addClickListener(e -> {
            if (gridBView == null) gridBView = new GridView();
            setContent(gridBView);
        });
        addToNavbar(gridB);
    }
}
```

`MainView` is an `AppLayout` used to switch the contents of the `AppLayout` from `GridView` to `EmptyView` and back.

Use Case 2 is: When returning to `GridView`, the `GridView` should be exactly same state as before (which works fine with the `TextField`).

1. open `GridView` -> grid should not be filled with data
2. enter filter params (not shown in code)
3. click "refresh" to populate the grid
4. enter "Spiderman" in `TextField` "stateCheck"
5. switch to `EmptyView`
6. in the real app: do something in `EmptyView` and potentially other views
7. return to `GridView` -> the grid should **not reload the data**, it should just stay as it was - just like the `TextField` still displays "Spiderman", the grid should display the same data as before without reloading it.

Comment: I'd recommend separating the second use case to its own question.

Comment: I've intentionally created just one question, since I am looking for a solution to both problems in one grid and both use cases might influence each other.

Comment: Obviously, you want a solution for both problems, but as far as I can tell, they're not really related. It'll be easier to understand (and answer) questions the less there is going on.

Comment: Use Case 2 has been moved to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330474/vaadin-flow-returning-to-a-view-the-view-should-not-reload-data-from-the-backe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Case 1: In the callback check if you have filter parameters, return an empty set if not. Using the new V17+ API it would look like this:

```java
grid.setItems(query -> {
    if(filterParameters.isEmpty()) {
      // Return an empty stream
    } else {
      // Fetch from backend
    }
});
```

You can read more in the docs here: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/binding-data/data-provider (V19) or https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-data-provider (V14)

I would need more info on what you're currently doing to help out with Case 2. How are you constructing the view, what does your code look like? A full stack trace with the "Caused by" would also help.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I've added `MainView` and `GridView` code and tried to explain UseCase 2 in the original question. I still have to read through your links.

Comment: I guess, `count` callback has to be implemented similarly (if not relying on the 'no count' variant with other UX problems)?
Since my app needs this in quite a lot of grids, I was looking for a declarative solution like `grid.fetchOnFirstShow(boolean)` or `dataProvider.fetchOnFirstShow(boolean)` maybe using own `Grid` or `DataProvider` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend only setting the DataProvider to the Grid once the first filter parameter is set. The client-side Grid expects to receive the number of items it requires from the fetch query; it *might* work in some corner case if you don't provide the requested numbers of items from `fetch`, but it's not designed to behave like that.

Note that this applies specifically to using DataProviders with filters in Vaadin 14 series - Vaadin 17 introduced a new optional simplified way of fetching items, which changes this equation a bit. It's not backported to Vaadin 14 yet (currently planned for 14.7).

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about that yesterday. Does that also imply removing the DataProvider in `beforeLeave`? I'll try that later on. 
Do you have a link for the new Vaadin 17 behaviour?

Comment: Here is a quick overview: https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-17-is-packed-with-data-binding-improvements and here is the actual docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/binding-data/data-provider#lazy-data-binding-using-callbacks .

Comment: And I don't think you need to remove the DataProvider, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I have to remove it due to use case 2 (see enhanced explanation in original question). But setting it to `null` leads to a `NullPointerException`.