# Vaadin Flow: Returning to a view, the view should not reload data from the backend

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Split out from [Vaadin Dataprovider: how to avoid "auto-fetch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323526/vaadin-dataprovider-how-to-avoid-auto-fetch).

Given a Vaadin Flow 19 app with a `MainView extends AppLayout`, a `GridView` and an `EmptyView`
 And `@PreserveOnRefresh` annotation is used on `MainView`.

When returning to `GridView`, the `GridView` should be exactly in the same state as before:

1. open `GridView` using button in `MainView` for the first time -> Grid uses `DataProvider` to fetch data from backend
2. enter "Spiderman" in `TextField` with caption "stateCheck"
3. switch to `EmptyView` using button in `MainView`
4. in the real app: do something in `EmptyView` and potentially other views
5. return to `GridView` using button in `MainView` for the 2nd time

Then (1) the `TextField` with caption "stateCheck" should display the value  "Spiderman"
And (2) the grid should still show the same data as before; it should **not reload the data from the backend**

Observed behaviour:
(1) is ok, but (2) not: the grid always calls `fetch` method to get data from the backend.

How do I achieve the desired behavior?

---

Here's the code of my `GridView` which also fakes the backend `DataProvider`:

```
@Route(value = "grid", layout = MainView.class)
public class GridView extends VerticalLayout {
    public GridView() {
        final Grid<Person> g = new Grid(Person.class);
        g.setColumns("name");
        g.setDataProvider(DataProvider.fromCallbacks(q -> fetch(q), q -> count(q)));
        add(g);

        add(new TextField("State check"));
    }

    // fake DataProvider
    private int count(Query<Person, Void> q) { return 3; }

    private Stream<Person> fetch(Query<Person, Void> q) {
        q.getLimit(); //vaadin checks these have been called
        q.getOffset(); //vaadin checks these have been called
        System.out.println("fetching again");
        return Arrays.asList(new Person("1"), new Person("2"), new Person("3")).stream();
    }
}
```

`MainView` is used to switch between `GridView` and `EmptyView`

```
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MainView extends AppLayout {

    private Component emptyBView;
    private Component gridBView;

    public MainView() {
        final Button emptyB = new Button("Btn empty");
        emptyB.addClickListener(e -> {
            if (emptyBView == null) { emptyBView = new EmptyView();}
            setContent(emptyBView);
        });
        addToNavbar(emptyB);

        final Button gridB = new Button("Btn grid");
        gridB.addClickListener(e -> {
            if (gridBView == null) gridBView = new GridView();
            setContent(gridBView);
        });
        addToNavbar(gridB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `@PreserveOnRefresh` is meant to be used on the views with `@Route`. In your case, you are not using the router to navigate, but instead just manually switching the components. The issue that the `DataProvider` is called when the view is re-attached might be a bug.

Comment: This is actually intentional behavior. The server side dataprovider listener needs to be removed when component is detached and rewired on attaching. The reason is that otherwise there would be listeners accumulating and producing a memory leakage.

Comment: @MarcusHellberg I know, there is another (now solved) problem with `@Route` which led to this example code - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually intentional behavior. The server side dataprovider listener needs to be removed when component is detached and rewired on attaching. The reason is that otherwise there would be listeners accumulating and producing a memory leakage. If you think your users would be using refresh page often, you should consider adding a cache to your application to optimize performance.

Now one could entertain with the idea of having this kind of caching of previous loaded data behavior via API in Grid also in Vaadin framework, as it may or may not be desirable. It is application specific.

If the use case of refreshing is really to get the fresh data of live and active database, it is actually desired that data is loaded when page is refreshed.

If the desire is to avoid extra bombarding of DB as data is known to be static, you want to have caching.

Comment: Lets assume the following use case

1. open article grid, filter and select article 4711
2. start editing article 4711 in detail pane of article grid
3. switch to another view to look up a value
4. return to article grid to continue editing the article 4711
5. save article 4711

In this case, the user does not want to reload the article grid in step 4.

Comment: I am not talking about refreshing the page. It is just _returning to a previously opened view_.

It is merely what you call caching: _Keep the grid data_ until the _user_ explicitly decides to (re)load data from the backend. 
The reason is displaying consistent data (not avoiding roundtrips to the server).

So you're saying that this caching needs to be implemented within the application since Vaadin does not support it out-of-the box?
Have you got any hints where to start?

Comment: @sk_dev "Have you got any hints where to start?", ehcache is fairly popular solution for backend caching https://www.ehcache.org/

Comment: my question was more directed towards vaadin :-). I thought about Clientside/DataProvider or better serverside (backend)... but I guess this is an architecture thing I have to discuss within the team. Thanks so far